# Duplicate transactions when user refreshes during checkout

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, duplicates, checkout

I am using JSF to do a credit card checkout process:

**JSF**

```
<p:commandButton value="Complete Checkout" 
action="#{checkoutBean.checkout}" update="@form"/>
```

**Java Bean**

```
public void checkout(){
    //do lengthy credit card processing
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect(getNextUrl());
}
```

The problem is when the user refreshes during checkout I get a duplicate order going through.

How do I solve this?

Comment: During refresh? Without clicking the button once again?

Comment: The checkout method is called and processes the transaction but they refresh before the redirect is called. They then checkout again and the duplicate is produced.

Comment: Try disable button until action is not complete or display popup with image/processing related text

Comment: The problem is if they refresh the button will be enabled again...

Comment: You can use `disabled` attribute for preventing button click after action completion

Comment: @VasilLukach the disabled attribute will be reset when the user refreshes.